# how to change the value of GUI label when new updates are computed on a different thread

Tags: multithreading, c++11, gtk

This is simple program using c++11 but with GTK+ (not GTKmm) , i'm kind obliged to use GTK+ for some compatibility issues.
Obviously there are some things there that are wrong....

Like changing the label from a global callback function "update_link(...)" .

I would like to create a signal that is emitted as the counter in the computing function is incremented, so that the GUI display this incrementation as it happens.

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include<glib.h>
#include<glib/gstdio.h>
#include<iostream>
#include <thread> 
#include<string>
#include<mutex>
#include<time.h>
#include<regex.h>


#define BUILDER_GLADE_FILE "t_tool.glade"

using namespace std;



typedef struct GUI_data
{   
    GtkBuilder  *gtkBuilder;
    GtkWidget   *window;   
    GtkWidget   *quit_button;
    GtkWidget   *txtview;
    gchar       *filename;
    GtkLabel    *lab6;
    GtkLabel    *lab7;
    GtkLabel    *lab8;
    GtkLabel    *lab9;
    GtkTextBuffer   *buffview;
    GtkTextIter  start , iter, end;
} GUI_data; 



static void GUI_stuff(GUI_data *d,int);
void quit_gtk(GUI_data *d);
void computing(int&, GUI_data*);
void updateLink(GtkWidget *label, gpointer data);




int main (int argc,  char *argv[])
{
 int count(0);
 gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

 GUI_data d;
 thread first (GUI_stuff, &d, ref(count));     
 thread second (computing,ref(count),&d);
 first.join();
 second.join();

return 0;
}


void computing(int& count, GUI_data *d)
{
    for (int i=0; i<=100; i++)
    {
        count++;
        cout<<" Counter i is : "<<i<<endl;
        gtk_signal_emit_by_name(G_OBJECT(d->lab6), "Link_up");

    }
}




static void GUI_stuff(GUI_data *d, int count)
{

 GtkBuilder *gtkBuilder;
 gtkBuilder = gtk_builder_new();
 gtk_builder_add_from_file(gtkBuilder, BUILDER_GLADE_FILE , NULL);

 d->window   = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(gtkBuilder,"window1"));
 gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(d->window),"T Tool");
 d->quit_button = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(gtkBuilder,"Quit"));
 d->txtview = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(gtkBuilder,"textview1"));
 d->lab6 = GTK_LABEL(gtk_builder_get_object(gtkBuilder,"label6"));
 d->lab7 = GTK_LABEL(gtk_builder_get_object(gtkBuilder,"label7"));
 d->lab8 = GTK_LABEL(gtk_builder_get_object(gtkBuilder,"label8"));
 d->lab9 = GTK_LABEL(gtk_builder_get_object(gtkBuilder,"label9"));


 GtkTextBuffer *buffview;
 GtkTextIter start , iter, end;



// gtk_label_set_text(lab6,std::to_string(count).c_str());
 gtk_label_set_text(d->lab6, " fills P status ");
 gtk_label_set_text(d->lab7, " fills P counter ");
 gtk_label_set_text(d->lab8, " fills R status ");
 gtk_label_set_text(d->lab9, " fills R counter ");


 buffview= gtk_text_view_get_buffer(GTK_TEXT_VIEW(d->txtview));
 gtk_text_buffer_get_iter_at_offset(buffview,&iter, 0);
 gtk_text_buffer_insert(buffview,&iter," This to show things",-1);


 g_signal_new("Link_up",G_TYPE_OBJECT, G_SIGNAL_RUN_FIRST,0, NULL, NULL,g_cclosure_marshal_VOID__POINTER,G_TYPE_NONE, 1, G_TYPE_POINTER);


 g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(d->lab6),"Link_up", G_CALLBACK(updateLink), &count);
 g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(d->window), "destroy", G_CALLBACK(quit_gtk), NULL);
 g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(d->quit_button), "activate", G_CALLBACK(quit_gtk), NULL);

 g_object_unref(G_OBJECT(gtkBuilder)) ;
 gtk_widget_show(d->window);
 gtk_main();

}



void updateLink(Gtklabel *label, gpointer data)
{
int *p =data;
gtk_label_set_text(label,std::to_string(*p).c_str());
}

void quit_gtk(GUI_data *d)
{
gtk_main_quit();
}
```

The error i get

```
    $ g++ -std=c++11  -Wall `pkg-config --libs --cflags gtk+-3.0` main.cpp -o gtkcpp
main.cpp: In function ‘void computing(int&, GUI_data*)’:
main.cpp:68:55: error: ‘gtk_signal_emit_by_name’ was not declared in this scope
   gtk_signal_emit_by_name(G_OBJECT(d->lab6), "Link_up");
                                                       ^
main.cpp: In function ‘void GUI_stuff(GUI_data*, int)’:
main.cpp:94:14: warning: unused variable ‘start’ [-Wunused-variable]
  GtkTextIter start , iter, end;
              ^
main.cpp:94:28: warning: unused variable ‘end’ [-Wunused-variable]
  GtkTextIter start , iter, end;
                            ^
main.cpp: At global scope:
main.cpp:125:17: error: variable or field ‘updateLink’ declared void
 void updateLink(Gtklabel *label, gpointer data)
                 ^
main.cpp:125:17: error: ‘Gtklabel’ was not declared in this scope
main.cpp:125:27: error: ‘label’ was not declared in this scope
 void updateLink(Gtklabel *label, gpointer data)
                           ^
main.cpp:125:43: error: expected primary-expression before ‘data’
 void updateLink(Gtklabel *label, gpointer data)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your compiler errors are due to typos.

1. It's `g_signal_emit_by_name()`, not `gtk_signal_emit_by_name()`. GObject functions, such as those regarding signals, use `g_` prefixes.
2. In your declaration of `updateLink()` you use `Gtklabel` instead of `GtkLabel`.

---

Now we can talk about what you want to do: update the `GtkLabel` from a different thread.

All signals have to be formally registered using `g_signal_new()`. This is usually done in the class initialization function, which sets up everything shared by all instances of a class. I don't know if you can even add signals later like that.

However, even if you did manage to add your `link_up` signal to `GtkLabel`, a bigger question is whether your `g_signal_emit_by_name()` call will run on the GUI thread. I myself and others have asked this question in different forms elsewhere in the past, and looking back at my logs, it appears there is no such guarantee.

So in general, **you don't want to do what you want to do (update the label from another thread) that way**.

You will want to instead use the [`gdk_threads_add_idle()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/gdk3-Threads.html#gdk-threads-add-idle) function (note the `gdk_` prefix this time) to add a callback that will call `gtk_label_set_text()` on the main thread. For example, you could do

```
gboolean updateLinks(gpointer data)
{
    int *p =data;
    gtk_label_set_text(label,std::to_string(*p).c_str());
    return FALSE; // don't run this particular instance again
}

// in computing()
gdk_threads_add_idle(updateLinks, &count);
```

`gdk_threads_add_idle()` specifically queues your function to run when no other events are pending. You can even schedule such a function to run repeatedly. Read the documentation for more details.

Note that `gdk_threads_add_idle()` returns immediately; if you want `computing()` to wait for the callback to finish running before it continues, you will need to write the synchronization code yourself.

Comment: Please pay attention to the lifespan of `count` it probably cannot have been destroyed by the time your callback has been called.

Comment: Yes; for that you can either do the memory management yourself (`new int(xx)`/`delete data`) or use macros like `GINT_TO_POINTER()`/`GPOINTER_TO_INT()` and its like (but be aware of sizing constraints with those).